# Why coroutine is always active when using NetworkBoundResource

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am using network bound resource to cache my search results as follows

```
inline fun <ResultType, RequestType> networkBoundResource(
    crossinline query: suspend () -> Flow<ResultType>,
    crossinline fetch: suspend () -> RequestType,
    crossinline saveFetchResult: suspend (RequestType) -> Unit,
    crossinline shouldFetch: (ResultType) -> Boolean = { true }
) = flow {
    val data = query().first()
    val flow = if (shouldFetch(data)) {
        emit(Resource.Loading(data))
        try {
            saveFetchResult(fetch())
            query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            query().map { Resource.Error(throwable, it) }
        }
    } else {
        query().map { Resource.Success(it) }
    }

    emitAll(flow)
}
```

On my repository I have the following implementation for search mechanism

```
override fun searchPodcasts(term: String) = networkBoundResource(
        query = {
            val search = podcastDao.loadSearchResult(term)
            podcastDao.loadPodcastOrdered(search?.collectionIds ?: emptyList())
        },

        fetch = {
            itunesService.searchPodcasts(term)
        },

        saveFetchResult = { response ->
            val ids = response.results.map { it.collectionId }
            val searchResult = PodcastSearchResult(term, ids, response.resultCount)
            val pods = response.toPodcasts()

            db.runInTransaction {
                podcastDao.insertPodcasts(pods)
                podcastDao.insertSearchResult(searchResult)
            }
        },

        shouldFetch = { data ->
            data.isNullOrEmpty()
        }

    ).flowOn(ioDispatcher)
```

Then after I call this method on my view model when user perform a search

```
fun onSearchPodcast(term: String) {
        // Prevent user perform same search while work is still on progress
        if (term == query && searchJob?.isActive == true) return

        query = term

        _searchPodcasts.value = emptyList()

        showLive()

        searchJob?.cancel()
        searchJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            itunesRepo.searchPodcasts(term)
                .collect { result ->
                    Timber.d("Mtali : $result")
                    when(result) {
                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            spinner(true)
                            if (!result.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                _searchPodcasts.value = result.data.toIPodcasts()
                            }
                        }

                        is Resource.Error -> {
                            message(result.error?.message)
                            spinner(false)
                        }

                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            if (result.data.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                                message("Empty response")
                            } else {
                                _searchPodcasts.value = result.data.toIPodcasts()
                            }
                            spinner(false)
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

My dao

```
@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insertSearchResult(result: PodcastSearchResult)

@Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
fun insertPodcasts(podcasts: List<Podcast>)

@Query("SELECT * FROM Podcast WHERE collectionId in (:collectIds)")
fun loadPodcastsById(collectIds: List<Long>): Flow<List<Podcast>>

@Query("SELECT * FROM PodcastSearchResult WHERE term = :term")
suspend fun loadSearchResult(term: String): PodcastSearchResult?

fun loadPodcastOrdered(ids: List<Long>): Flow<List<Podcast>> {
    val order = SparseLongArray()
    ids.withIndex().forEach {
        order.put(it.value.toInt(), it.index.toLong())
    }
    return loadPodcastsById(ids).map { podcasts ->
        podcasts.sortedWith(compareBy { order.get(it.collectionId.toInt()) })
    }
}
```

On the first search it works great but for some reasons when I perform another search with same term/query the job is always active `searchJob?.isActive` even though it collected and displayed the result successfully the last time

Comment: Can you show your DAO function declarations that you're using here, like `loadPodcastOrdered()`?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why `loadPodcastOrdered()` returns a flow, but you use it as a one shot suspend function?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what it's supposed to be doing. The `query` is a function that returns a Flow, so it's a factory, but why is it a factory? Why not just have a Flow parameter directly? Flows are typically cold so I don't see what the factory buys you. Anyway, you retrieve the first value of this Flow, but then you are trying to map values of the Flow as your output, so the first value is used twice (since the DAO will be producing Flows that always start by emitting the current value).

Comment: From what I understand, I need a single source of truth (Database in this case) query factory return flow. If database has some data cached data I display it first (wrapped in Resource.Loading) but continue on the background to fetch fresh data, saving data on database will result to another emit on query factory, I map new data to a wrapper Resource.Success. Not sure if my explanation is clear @Tenfour04

Comment: Your factory doesn’t accomplish anything. Every time you call the DAO function it is returning an equivalent cold Flow instance.

Comment: First of all, I'm not at all familiar with this DB framework (I guess it is Room). However, if `loadPodcastsById()` returns `Flow` then doesn't it mean it emits updates on DB objects? If yes, it means this flow never finishes. As a result, `searchPodcasts()` flow also never finishes and you never finish collecting items from it, In other words, `searchJob` does not finish, because it waits for `Podcast` updates indefinitely. But this is just my guess. Forgive me if I just said something that is not at all true.

Comment: You are correct @broot I was debugging and found what you explained … flow never finishes collecting from `loadPodcastOrdered`

Answer (score 1):

From comments I later found out that collect never finishes as it always collect stream of data from database

From the documentation [Flow cancellation checks](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/flow.html#flow-cancellation-checks)

> For convenience, the flow builder performs additional ensureActive checks for cancellation on each emitted value

So I can call `cancel()` inside `collect {}` whenever I want to cancel flow collection.

```
.collect { result ->
    when (result) {
        is Resource.Loading -> {
        
        }

        is Resource.Error -> {
            // ...
            cancel()
        }

        is Resource.Success -> {
            // ...
            cancel()
        }
    }
}
```

You can also do

```
.cancellable()
.collect {
    // As above
}
```